# Why ORACLE TO_DATE() function can receive any date format?

Tags: oracle

Why ORACLE `TO_DATE()` function can receive any date format ? as like

```
insert into testtest values (to_date('2015-09-22 23:19:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150923 23:20:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150927233001','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150925','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

these all are correct.

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE TO_DATE() function can receive any date format of above example cause

A format model is a character literal that describes the format of datetime or numeric data stored in a character string. A format model does not change the internal representation of the value in the database. When you convert a character string into a date or number, a format model determines how Oracle Database interprets the string.
Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

When a date conversion fails, Oracle tries some similar formats to try succeed. Before Oracle 8i there was some problems on this issues, But now Oracle has a strong mechanism behind date funcations or date string.

This table is in the Format Model section of the SQL Reference

Original Format Element Additional Format Elements to Try if Original fails
[image]

Ref: http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/dates_8i.htm

Answer (score 1):

As @Famous said, *by default* Oracle tries various formats to try to interpret the string, [as noted in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A__CDEHIFJA):

> Oracle Database converts strings to dates with some flexibility. For example, when the `TO_DATE` function is used, a format model containing punctuation characters matches an input string lacking some or all of these characters, provided each numerical element in the input string contains the maximum allowed number of digits—for example, two digits '05' for 'MM' or four digits '2007' for 'YYYY'.

But you can alter that behaviour [with the `FX` format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

> **FX**
>
> Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and datetime format model of a `TO_DATE` function:
>
> - Punctuation and quoted text in the character argument must exactly match (except for case) the corresponding parts of the format model.
> - The character argument cannot have extra blanks. Without `FX`, Oracle ignores extra blanks.
> - Numeric data in the character argument must have the same number of digits as the corresponding element in the format model. Without `FX`, numbers in the character argument can omit leading zeros.
>     When `FX` is enabled, you can disable this check for leading zeros by using the FM modifier as well.
>
> If any portion of the character argument violates any of these conditions, then Oracle returns an error message.

So if you add that modifier:

```
insert into testtest values (to_date('2015-09-22 23:19:00','FXYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150923 23:20:00','FXYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150927233001','FXYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

insert into testtest values (to_date('20150925','FXYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

then the first statement still works, but the other three all get error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```